# create span and append text

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create spans and append split string as characters within each span. So, given the message below, it'd be something like `<span>t</span><span>h</span>` etc...

For some reason, I'm getting this error when I append to document body. Why?

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

            scramble();

            function scramble () {                  
                var message = "this is a message";
                for (var i = 0; i < message.split("").length; i++) {
                    var letter = document.createElement('span');
                    letter.innerHTML = message.split("")[i];
                    document.body.appendChild(letter);
                    //document.getElementById("body").appendChild(letter);
                }
            }               
            function log (w) {
                console.log(w);
            }


    </script>
</head>
<body>      
</body>
</html>
```

I've also tried `document.getElementById("body").appendChild(letter);` with the same error.

Stack trace:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
 myFunc
 (anonymous function)
```

Comment: I tried it in jsfiddle and it works just fine

Comment: yeah ^that. what browser are you using?

Comment: chrome. I've added more above

Comment: Could you post full example code (html and js) that exhibits the problem you are describing?

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann Added above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to put your JavaScript at the bottom (anywhere below or inside the `body` tag).

Or use this if you don't have jQuery :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //do work
});
```

Or if you have jQuery :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //do work
});
```

`document.body` still doesn't exist by the time `scramble()` is called.

---

References :

[document.ready without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

Comment: Yup. And by "at the bottom", you mean as the last child of the `body` element. However, since _this code_ in particular is only accessing `document.body`, it would work even as the first child of `body`.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up @Spooky, I edited in the definition of *bottom* in the answer to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are calling the "scramble" method from within the HEAD tag before the BODY is actually rendered. Make the call to "scramble" run during the "unload" event or just call it from a SCRIPT tag places just before the closing BODY tags at the bottom of the page.